# TypeScript tuples conditional comparison always evaluates to false

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics, conditional-types

This is very straightforward, here is [the link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20If%3C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20TCond%20extends%20boolean%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20TIfTrue%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20TElse%0D%0A%3E%20%3D%20%5BTCond%5D%20extends%20%5Btrue%5D%20%3F%20TIfTrue%20%3A%20TElse%3B%20%2F%2F%20if%20you%20remove%20tuples%2C%20it%20works%20%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Not%3CT%20extends%20boolean%3E%20%3D%20If%3C(T)%2C%20false%2C%20true%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20IsNever%3CTSuspect%3E%20%3D%20TSuspect%20extends%20never%20%3F%20true%20%3A%20false%3B%0D%0A%20%0D%0Atype%20AssertFalse%3CTSuspect%20extends%20false%3E%20%3D%20TSuspect%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20V~~%20always%20true%20%0D%0Atype%20And%3CT%20extends%20boolean%5B%5D%3E%20%3D%20Not%3CNot%3CIsNever%3CExtract%3CT%5Bnumber%5D%2C%20false%3E%3E%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20AndExpected%3CT%20extends%20boolean%5B%5D%3E%20%3D%20IsNever%3CExtract%3CT%5Bnumber%5D%2C%20false%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20expected%3A%0D%0Atype%20t0%20%3D%20Not%3Ctrue%3E%3B%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20false%0D%0Atype%20t1%20%3D%20Not%3Cfalse%3E%3B%20%20%20%2F%2F%20true%0D%0Atype%20t2%20%3D%20Not%3Cboolean%3E%3B%20%2F%2F%20true%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20t3%20%3D%20AssertFalse%3CAnd%3C%5Bfalse%5D%3E%3E%3B%20%2F%2F%20%3F%3F%3F%3F%0D%0Atype%20t4%20%3D%20AssertFalse%3CAndExpected%3C%5Bfalse%5D%3E%3E%3B)

As I have noticed, when you remove tuple type from condition in `If<>` everything goes as expected. But I don't want to do it (`t2` assertion blows), moreover I'd like to understand wy this happens. Is this just a bug? Why `And<>` type always expands to `true`?

```
type If<
    TCond extends boolean,
    TIfTrue,
    TElse
> = [TCond] extends [true] ? TIfTrue : TElse; // if you remove tuples, it works 

type Not<T extends boolean> = If<(T), false, true>;

type IsNever<TSuspect> = TSuspect extends never ? true : false;

type AssertFalse<TSuspect extends false> = TSuspect;
type AssertTrue <TSuspect extends true> = TSuspect;

//   V~~ always true 
type And<T extends boolean[]> = Not<Not<IsNever<Extract<T[number], false>>>>;

type AndExpected<T extends boolean[]> = IsNever<Extract<T[number], false>>;


type t0 = AssertFalse<Not<true>>;  
type t1 = AssertTrue<Not<false>>;  
type t2 = AssertTrue<Not<boolean>>;

type t3 = AssertFalse<And<[false]>>; // ????
type t4 = AssertFalse<AndExpected<[false]>>;
```

Comment: Isn't `Extract<T[number], false>` - `never`? So isn't `Not<Not<IsNever<Extract<T[number], false>>>>` - `true`?

Comment: @zerkms Not always, that's why I check it with `IsNever<>`

Comment: In what case `Extract<T[number], false>` isn't never?

Comment: @zerkms [When there is no false in array values union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20t0%20%3D%20Extract%3Ctrue%5B%5D%5Bnumber%5D%2C%20false%3E%3B%0D%0Atype%20t1%20%3D%20Extract%3C%5Btrue%5D%5Bnumber%5D%2C%20false%3E%3B%0D%0Atype%20t2%20%3D%20Extract%3Cstring%5B%5D%5Bnumber%5D%2C%20false%3E%3B) (EDIT)

Comment: In that link all types (`t0`, `t1`, `t2`) are `never` (EDIT)

Comment: @zerkms You can check it in the playground, just put your pointer on the type and look at the tooltip.

Comment: It shows all of them are `never`. Oh right `type t0 = Extract<false[][number], false>;` - this would be `false` indeed.

Comment: @zerkms Obviuosly, I showed you examples when `Extract<>` expands to `never`

Comment: Exactly, and I initially asked when it's **NOT** `never` :-D (thanks for providing this example though)

Comment: @zerkms [Here you are](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20t0%20%3D%20Extract%3Cboolean%5B%5D%5Bnumber%5D%2C%20false%3E%3B%0D%0Atype%20t1%20%3D%20Extract%3C%5Bfalse%2C%20true%5D%5Bnumber%5D%2C%20false%3E%3B%0D%0Atype%20t2%20%3D%20Extract%3C%5Bfalse%5D%5Bnumber%5D%2C%20false%3E%3B)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191052/discussion-between-veetaha-and-zerkms).

Comment: @Veetaha this might be a bug, a much smaller repro: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Not%3CT%20extends%20boolean%3E%20%3D%20%5BT%5D%20extends%20%5Btrue%5D%20%3F%20false%20%3A%20true%3B%0D%0Atype%20And%3CT%20extends%20boolean%3E%20%3D%20Not%3CNot%3CT%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20t10%20%3D%20Not%3CNot%3Cfalse%3E%3E%20%2F%2F%20false%0D%0Atype%20t11%20%3D%20And%3Cfalse%3E%20%2F%2F%20true%0D%0A

Comment: I feel like I've hit bugs like this also, and usually just work around them by putting intermediate results into default type parameters (e.g., `And<T, N=Not<T>> = Not<N>`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'll try to explain why If with tuples differs from If without tuples:

```
type If<
    TCond extends boolean,
    TIfTrue,
    TElse
> = [TCond] extends [true] ? TIfTrue : TElse; // if you remove tuples, it works 

type If2<
    TCond extends boolean,
    TIfTrue,
    TElse
> = TCond extends true ? TIfTrue : TElse;  


type Not<T extends boolean> = If<(T), false, true>;
type Not2<T extends boolean> = If2<(T), false, true>;

// with tuples, Not<boolean> is true because that's how you set it up
type A1 = Not<boolean>; // true
type A2 = Not<true>;    // false
type A3 = Not<false>;   // true

// without typles, TCond extends true is distributive over union types,
// and boolean is really just a union of true | false,
// so Not2<boolean> is boolean 
type B1 = Not2<boolean>; // boolean 
type B2 = Not2<true>;    // false
type B3 = Not2<false>;   // true
```

ok, now to the question. Here's the strange thing I (and Titian Cernicova-Dragomir) found:

```
type SameAsT<T extends boolean> = Not<Not<T>>;
type X1 = SameAsT<false>; // true !
type X2 = SameAsT<true>; // true again

// but why?
```

If you expand all the literal types, it works as expected:

```
type ReallyNotFalse = [false] extends [true] ? false : true; // true
type ReallyNotNotFalse = [([false] extends [true] ? false : true)] extends [true] ? false : true; // false
```

Looks like a bug in the compiler.

Incidentally, `Not` based on `If` without tuples works as expected

```
type SameAsT2<T extends boolean> = Not2<Not2<T>>;
type Y1 = SameAsT2<false>; // false
type Y2 = SameAsT2<true>; // true
```

So, it's possible to use some other way to suppress distributive union type in conditions and to make the code in question work. One way is to add superfluous condition which always evaluates to true, and does not have `TCond` as the type being checked:

```
type If<
    TCond extends boolean,
    TIfTrue,
    TElse
> = {} extends TCond ? TCond extends true ? TIfTrue : TElse : never; 

type Not<T extends boolean> = If<(T), false, true>;

type IsNever<TSuspect> = TSuspect extends never ? true : false;

type AssertFalse<TSuspect extends false> = TSuspect;
type AssertTrue <TSuspect extends true> = TSuspect;

//   V~~ always true 
type And<T extends boolean[]> = Not<Not<IsNever<Extract<T[number], false>>>>;

type AndExpected<T extends boolean[]> = IsNever<Extract<T[number], false>>;


type t0 = AssertFalse<Not<true>>;  
type t1 = AssertTrue<Not<false>>;  
type t2 = AssertTrue<Not<boolean>>;

type t3 = AssertFalse<And<[false]>>; 
type t4 = AssertFalse<AndExpected<[false]>>;
```